# react final form validation messages in array

Tags: react-final-form

I am sending server-side validation back from Mongoose, I have manipulated the JSON to this structure which I though React-Final-Form required:

```
{
  "persons": [
    {
      "firstName": "Path `firstName` is required."
    },
    {
      "secondName": "Path `secondName` is required."
    }
  ]
}
```

My values are in this structure but when I return the errors only the first error message is displayed.

```
                   validate={() => {
                        return this.props.validationErrors && 
                         this.props.validationErrors.landlord
                            ? this.props.validationErrors.landlord
                            : {};
                    }}
```

Each error displays if only one entry in the array

Answer (score 0):

I see the mistake now, structure of my errors coming back needs to be:

```
const errors = [{
    firstName: 'Here is an error',
    secondName: 'Here is an error'
}]
```